# What is the correct syntax for passing an array from a function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I'm completely new to React, and I'm struggling with passing an array of strings from one component to another.

I've been trying to understand [this](https://mevasanth.medium.com/react-problems-with-passing-array-as-a-prop-a124fa02d511) to help me, but I'm having trouble applying the logic to my specific situation. For more context see this below:

Basically, I have this:

```
export default function TitleData(){
  return (
     ["My Title Test"]
    );
}
```

I am attempting to pass the array returned by the `TitleData` function to this function.

```
import './App.css'
import AntButton from './hover-click-button'
import TitleData from './web-data/title-data'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <main>
     <AntButton title={TitleData[0]} />
    </main>
  )
}
```

I am attempting to pass the value at index 0 from TitleData as props to the `AntButton`, but I am not receiving any result. The `AntButton` should produce a button with a title.

Here's the error I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Seems like you want `TitleData()[0]`

Comment: @Unmitigated yes I want `TitleData()[0]` to be passed in my `props` for `AntButton` function.

Answer (score 1):

You may also try this simpler way:

```
export default function App() {
  const titleArray = TitleData(); // Just simply call the function to get the array
  return (
    <main>
      <AntButton title={titleArray[0]} />
    </main>
  );
}
```

Reference at [React Function Component: Event Handler](https://www.knowledgehut.com/blog/web-development/react-functional-components)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To pass an array as a prop to a component in React, you can wrap the array in curly braces. In your case, you can pass the array from TitleData component to App component as follows:

```
import './App.css'
import AntButton from './hover-click-button'
import TitleData from './web-data/title-data'

export default function App() {
return (
<main>
<AntButton title={TitleData()[0]} />
</main>
)
}
```

Here, we are calling the TitleData function and passing the first element of the returned array as a prop to the AntButton component.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I am being routed to use [ref](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/findDOMNode#reading-components-own-dom-node-from-a-ref) based on my console log result. However, I am struggling to apply it to my array variable.

Comment: [see here the log error](https://imgur.com/a/EGjeg1O)

Comment: can you write the log here i cant open it in imgur for some reson

Comment: `Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of DomWrapper4 which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference. Learn more about using refs safely here: https://reactjs.org/link/strict-mode-find-node`